# translate coordinate method java

Tags: java, methods

I can't seem to get my transform method right. Any suggestions on how I could make the method translate the point better? i.e. when this method is invoked, it should be able to give the new point. Also I'm having issues creating the slope method...I know slope is y2-y1/x2-x1 but how would I make that into a method. Is there a Math class I can import for the slope? Thanks much appreciated

```
       import java.util.*;
        public class Point {
        private int x; // to store variables for x & y
        private int y;
        private double slope;



       //default constructor
          public Point () {
           double x = 0;
           double y = 0;
          } 

       //alternate constructor
       public Point (double x1, double y1) {
        double x = x1;
        double y = y1;

         }

       //set coordinates
       public void setCoord (double x1, double y1){
        double x = x1;
        double y = y1;
         }
      //print method
      public void print () {
        System.out.print(x + "," + y);
         }

      //toString Method
       public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
         }

       public int getX() {
         return x;
          }

       public int getY() {
        return y;
          }

       public void equals () {
         if (x==y) 
           System.out.println(" Coordinates are the same ");
         else {
           System.out.println(" Coordinates are different ");
            }
         }

         public void copy(Point temp) {
          x=temp.x;
          y=temp.y;
           }

         public Point getCopy() {
         Point temp = new Point();
           temp.x = x;
           temp.y = y;

            return temp;
            }

         public void distanceFromOrigin(int x1, int y1) {
          double dx = x-x1;
          double dy = y-y1;
          }
       //calculate the distance from one point to another
           public void distance (double x1, double y1) {
            double distance = Math.sqrt((x * x1) + (y * y1));
           }
       //shift the location of a point by a given amount
          public void transform (double dx, double dy) { 
           double transform = ((x+dx) (y+dy));

           }
       // returns true if any given point lines up horizontally with a given point.
           public boolean isHorizontal () {
             return true;

             }
       // returns true if any given point lines up vertically with a given point.
            public boolean isVertical () {
              return true;
            }
       // returns the slope of the line 
            public double slope() {
               return slope;
           }
       }
```

Comment: All your methods are assigning the values of x1 and y1 to x and y respectively except a few; so you are subtracting x1 from x,i.e.,x-x1=0,apparently!

Comment: double transform = (dy-y)/(dx-x);

Comment: //how about for slope?

Comment: @user3697635-What does your `transform()` method do?Has ra2085 mentioned correct formula for transform? `Slope=dy/dx` simply;

Comment: Why are your x and y coordinates stored as integers, but passed in the parameters as doubles?

Comment: Is your `distanceFromOrigin` method supposed to calculate the distance of the point from the origin (0,0) or the distance between two points?

Comment: And given that your `Point` object represents a single point in 2d space, it should not have a `slope` attribute.

Comment: the distance from origin should calculate the distance from (0,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void equals (Object o) {
    if(o instanceof Point) {
        Point p = (Point)o;
        return p.x == x && p.y == y;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public Point getCopy() {
    return new Point(x, y);
}

public double slope(Point otherPoint) {
    return ((double)(otherPoint.y - y)) / ((double)(otherPoint.x / x));
}

public double distance (Point otherPoint) {
    double dx = otherPoint.x - x;
    double dy = otherPoint.y - y;
    return Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
}

public double distanceFromOrigin() {
    return distance(new Point(0, 0));
}

public boolean isHorizontal (Point otherPoint) {
    return otherPoint.y == y;
}

public boolean isVertical(Point otherPoint) {
    return otherPoint.x == x;
}

public void transform (double dx, double dy) {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}
```